# Caching a partial response

Tags: java, json, rest, caching, jersey

How to cache part of a json response?

e.g-

let's say i have a response

```
{
 k1: v1,
 k2: v2,
 k3: v3,
 k4: v4
}
```

I know only k1 and k3 can be cached as k2 and k4 keep on changing frequently.

Next time I'll just send k2 and k4 in server response if k1 and k3's value doesn't change. 
e.g - `{k2: v2,  k4: v4 }`

What is standard to implement such construct? I don't want the client to decide what all fields are cacheable, Server will decide this.

Comment: Do I understand right that a client always sends the same json?

Comment: @dehasi it&#39;s server which sending json not client.